# Comparison sheet for switch to Orion

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I can't find a resource that clarifies the programming differences between Polaris and Orion versions. I've been googling for a few days now.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you already read this article written by Jukka Niiranen

[The Next Dynamics CRM User Experience: Orion](http://niiranen.eu/crm/2013/03/the-next-dynamics-crm-user-experience-orion/)

I think Gemini release will bring (at least) the possibility to use Xrm javascript with the new forms (actually is really a shame to don't be able to pre-fill a field or to do some show/hide logic) and provide the xml definition that will replace the ribbon.

Comment: This was new to me. What do you men "not able to pre-fill"?

Comment: for example to set a DateTime field to the current date on create

Comment: That was a surprise. Any (good and rational) reason for such design?

Comment: most of the time for custom fields (for example a "First Phone Call Date" inside lead) but for standard fields as well (set "Follow Up By" inside incident 3 days from now)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is such a document yet. Before we start with Orion, we have to pass Gemini, first. And given the inconsistency between road maps and reality this far, it could as well be that Orion will be known as CRM-2014.